# Active record query with many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a Rails 4 app and I'm try to compose a simple query on a many to many relation.

I have a Content model that has many section.

In my content page I want to show some related.

A related content must have at least one of the section of my content and my query must exclude my main content.

I have

```
c = Content.find(5)
c.section_ids return [2,4,6]
```

How can I query for contents where section are IN c.section_ids exluding c.id from the results?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
section_ids = c.section_ids.reject { |s| s == c.id }
Content.joins(:sections).where('sections.section_id in (?)', section_ids)
```